# onScroll Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have function that changes the background of a div on mouse scroll, but because firefox and IE have smooth scroll turned on, it's becoming messy and skips images.

Is there a better way to debounce and have a better and smoother scrolling? Like on http://www.airnauts.com ?

Here's my website so you can have a look at the issue: http://denea.comeze.com

Here's my JS (I'm new to javascript, so don't judge me hardly please):

```
var numberofscroll = 0;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var dontHandle = false;
    $("#home").scroll(function () {
    if (dontHandle) return;
        dontHandle = true;
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        (st > lastScrollTop) ? numberofscroll++ : numberofscroll--;
        console.log(numberofscroll);
        console.log(lastScrollTop);
        console.log(st);
        if (numberofscroll<2){
            change_background2(numberofscroll);
        }
        else if (numberofscroll<3){
            change_background3(numberofscroll);
        }
        else if (numberofscroll<4){
            change_background4(numberofscroll);
        }

        lastScrollTop = st;

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            dontHandle = false;
        }, 290);
    });
```

Comment: 1st thing : use a spirit with all your image on it or pre-load the image...

Comment: @Blag, I tried using a sprite, but It messed up if I would resize the window, so I decided to change classes's background.For now I need to fix this smooth scrolling thing